# real time database trigger notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Down below is the trigger for the change in the real time database

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.notification = functions.database.ref('/chatroom-98902/').onWrite(event => {

   var topic = 'Warning';

   var message ={
       data :{
           title:"Warning",
           body:"123"
        },
       topic: topic
    };
    admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:",response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:",error);
    });

});
```

but when i test on my phone it won't trigger while the changing in the database,
is there any problem about my code?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Cloud Functions have been recently updated to V 1.0 with some changes in the syntax, see:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

If you are using this new version you have to change your code from:

```
exports.notification = functions.database.ref('/chatroom-98902/').onWrite(event => {
```

to

```
exports.notification = functions.database.ref('/chatroom-98902/').onWrite((change, context) => {
```

To check which version you are using, look into your `package.json` file (`dependencies` node)

Comment: i change my code as you recommended, but when i change my real time database, it still can't get a notification.

Comment: And this are two of error  "Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions" , "
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" . Will it be the problem? thanks a lot for answering me.